# Largest value of an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, logic

Suppose I give myself symbols of function (eg $\exp$, $\sqrt{}$...), symbols of constants (eg $1$, $e$, $\pi$...) and symbols of operations (eg $+$, $\times$,...). I allow myself to use each one a certain amount of times and I wonder, among the expressions I can form, which one has largest value when evaluated.
In a particular case I can try each possibility, but I would like to know if there is a general theory about related issues.

Comment: Of all the ordinary operations, exponentiation makes things bigger fastest.

Comment: I know, that was not my question.

Comment: Your question is rather vague.  For example $x{^{x^{x^{...}}}}$ gives larger numbers for larger x and number of exponents.  Without well defined rules, this can go on indefinitely.

Comment: So, I have a fixed set of symbols, and for each one I allow myself to use it a fixed number of time. This way, I can write finitely many expressions. In each special instance of this problem I can try and compare each possible expression. My question was rather: are there general results about this kind of problems?

Comment: General results?  I have no idea, but I doubt it.

Comment: Well, at the level of generality I stated things, I agree there is probably nothing interesting to say. But I wonder if some interesting subclasses of this problem have been studied.